# Using ngFor inside another ngFor?

Tags: angular

In my Angular program, I'm trying to print out a table for each person in an array that includes all of the days they have taken off. The array with the employees in it is `empInfo` and the array with the days they have taken off is `ptoData`. The field in both arrays is `EmpKey`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```html
      <div class="panel-body" style="padding-left: 0px;" *ngFor="let emp of empInfo">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>Employee: {{emp.EmpKey}} {{emp.FirstName}} {{emp.LastName}}</tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Date</td>
              <td>Hours</td>
              <td>Scheduled</td>
              <td>Notes</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <ng-container *ngIf="pto.EmpKey === emp.EmpKey">
              <ng-container *ngFor="let pto of of ptoData">
                <tr>
                  <td>{{pto.date}}</td>
                  <td>{{pto.hours}}</td>
                  <td>{{pto.scheduled}}</td>
                  <td>{{pto.notes}}</td>
                </tr>
              </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

but here's all that it's printing out:

[image]

If I remove `<ng-container *ngIf="pto.EmpKey === emp.EmpKey"></ng-container>`, it prints out this (which is still not what I'm looking for obviously, but it at least prints out the names):

[image]

Comment: `*ngFor="let pto of of ptoData"` looks wrong. Also the order of `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` seems wrong too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch the `<ng-container>` tags, the `pto` variable is not known yet in the first container. And yes, like pzaenger says, only use one `of` in your `*ngFor` ;)

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pto of ptoData">
   <ng-container *ngIf="pto.EmpKey === emp.EmpKey">
      <tr>
        <td>{{pto.date}}</td>
        <td>{{pto.hours}}</td>
        <td>{{pto.scheduled}}</td>
        <td>{{pto.notes}}</td>
      </tr>
   </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: thanks, much appreciated! and I didn't even notice the double `of` haha

Comment: should also use the `*ngIf` on the `tr` tag. No point in adding an extra `ng-container` here.